Do we have a bug caused by the Colorado transfer?
Since the sites moved to Colorado for the week I've seen an unexpected behavior, but only on Bricks.  It always shows me in the header that there is one suggested edit, but when I go to the review queues page or that particular queue it tells me it there are none.  This is happening to me on Linux and MacOS in up-to-date versions of Chrome.

Is it still there? I approved one suggested edit just now. It was your tag wiki edit, so I'm wondering if it was showing in your badge count, but not in your queue since you obviously can't approve your own edit.

That was it!  Thanks.

It still seems like a bug.

It basically is a bug, but I believe that it's also known behavior: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726. The review queue count is cached and is the same for all users. It's computationally expensive to personalize this for each user.

That's a totally legit compromise.  And now that I realize tag wiki edit could cause it I won't be surprised next time.  :)
